# Django allauth AssertionError

Tags: django, django-allauth

Hello received `AssertionError` when try to add

`ACCOUNT_USERNAME_VALIDATORS =
 ('allauth.socialaccount.providers.battlenet.validators.BattletagUsernameValidator',)`

Same happen when it is a list, and if i add just str , i am receiving error that `ACCOUNT_USERNAME_VALIDATORS` must be a list

Other allauth config

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
     # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT =5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT =300
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 5
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 3
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the full traceback you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much more context, could your issue be related to:
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/pull/1648

The solution proposed in the linked issue is:

```
# Use a string in settings
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_VALIDATORS = 'foobar.validators.username_validators'

# Return a list in the validators
def username_validators():
    return [
        socialaccount.providers.battlenet.validators.BattletagUsernameValidator,
    ]
```